# eclipse cross gcc toolchain wrapper plugin

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcc, eclipse-cdt, cross-compiling

I currently have Eclipse CDT working with a managed Cross GCC toolchain just fine. The only down side is any time I create a new project, I need to manually add all the special gcc flags for my cross gcc compiler. I know I can create a custom build plugin for eclipse, but is it easy to just call the cross gcc compiler with my custom flags, or do I have to figuratively reinvent the wheel by downloading the crossgcc source and modifying it? I ask this because I noticed the `org.eclipse.cdt.build.crossgcc` plugin is private and I can't use any of it. Does anyone know how to create a simple wrapper around Cross GCC toolchain? I want to be able to click "MyCustomToolchain" instead of having to configure Cross GCC.